# Deductions for non-residents while filing US taxes

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, non-resident, form-1040x

Do non-residents get any deductions while filing US taxes? I see they are not allowed the standard deduction. Are they not allowed any other deduction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, nonresident aliens are allowed certain itemized deductions. See Form 1040-NR Schedule A (which is on page 3 of the 1040-NR form) for a full list of which itemized deductions are allowed for nonresident aliens. If you are using the 1040-NR-EZ simplified form, only the itemized deduction for state or local income taxes is allowed.